# Javascript get nested element values

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html code as below:

```
<div class="formContent">                       
    <label for="title">Data Collection Title:</label><p>Western Australia</p><br/>
    <label for="description">Description</label><p>Examples of ...</p><br/>
</div>
```

How can I access the values, e.g., Western Australia and Examples of... using JavaScript?

Comment: `$('.formContent p').text()`

Comment: Or better $('label[for="title"] p').text()

Comment: $('label[for="title"] p').text() --> does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vanilla:

```
var txt = document.querySelector('.formContent label[for="title"]').nextSibling.textContent;
console.log(txt);
```

jQuery:

```
var txt = $('.formContent label[for="title"]').next("p").text();
console.log(txt);
```

Comment: this also works : document.write($('label[for="title"]').next().text())

Comment: leaving aside the document.write thing, it's a good habit to be as specific as you can with selectors, including their ancestor nodes when possible so the code doesn't have to search the entire tree to find that one label. Also why using IDs is preferable to classes (because there can be only one, so the code zooms straight in). May not be noticeable on small documents but with thousands of nodes and a sloppy selector the code can lag half a second or more which is definitely noticeable and can seem like a long time when you're sitting there waiting for something to happen

Answer (score 0):

With plain JavaScript this is quite simple:

```
var p = document.querySelectorAll('.formContent p');
for (var i = 0, len = p.length; i < len; i++)
    console.log( p[i].textContent );
```

If you use jQuery the logic is the same:

```
$('.formContent p').each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll('.formContent p');
for (var i = 0, len = p.length; i < len; i++)
  console.log( p[i].textContent );
```

```html
<div class="formContent">                       
    <label for="title">Data Collection Title:</label><p>Western Australia</p><br/>
    <label for="description">Description</label><p>Examples of ...</p><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I access the value for a given label? e.g., label 'title' should return "Western Australia"